# Can you restrict the services a certificate can access on the client side?

Tags: encryption, tls, authentication

I have a verification certificate signed by my organisation’s CA, which I can use to authenticate my user account on intranet web services.

Is there someway I can sign a new certificate which can only authenticate to one specific web service. Or some other way to enable limited access to one web service by a script I don’t want to give full access to my verification certificate.

Unfortunately I don’t have access to modify the web service, which is running nginx.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing the concepts of authentication and authorization. The first is to know who the client is and the second to decide what this client can do. A client certificate in TLS is just used for **authentication**, i.e. like username + password but only better. If the service you want to access will accept this certificate as **authorized**  is fully up to this service.

> Is there someway I can sign a new certificate which can only authenticate to one specific web service.

First, you cannot usually create a new client certificate by using an existing client certificate. Also, given that you are not able to modify the service you have no way of specifying which authenticated clients are authorized for a specific service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For this particular web server authorization is given to anyone who can present a valid cert signed by the org CA. But I don't want to give the script access to this cert directly because the cert could be reused on different servers. In the SSH case it seems I can add constraints to certificates limiting their validity to a given host, I can't see such options for TLS/nginx.

Comment: I think I need to do a lot more reading on x509 certs.

Comment: *"In the SSH case it seems I can add constraints to certificates limiting their validity to a given host"* - no. First, SSH usually does not use certificates in the first place but only keys (can use certificates too though). Then, any restrictions on what a key can do are done on the server side, same as with HTTPS. If you don't have access to the server side of SSH you cannot restrict what a key can do there either.

Comment: Yes I realise keys are more common for SSH, but many large companies including Netflix and Facebook are moving over to certificates. SSH keys can have restrictions put on them including limiting what command they can do. These are then signed by the CA and dynamically applied to the remote system. I may have misunderstood presentations on very based SSH but they seem to allow remote restrictions as signed by the CA, not set by the remote system.

Comment: @User: You are right that the certificate can contain SSH restrictions, that was actually new for me. But it is still true that the client cannot create a new certificate based on an older one. And it is still true that it is up to the server to decide which key or certificate to accept (authentication) for a specific purpose (authorization).

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I agree I see no way this can work. Which is disappointing. I’ll accept your solution.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, it's not quite correct to say "a certificate is just used for authentication". Certificates can be (and usually are) limited to a certain usage, for example it may be only be used for SSL server authentication or S/MIME encryption. The fact that you cannot use any certificate to sign other certificates is due to this usage restriction. However, I don't know of a way to restrict a certificate to be used with a specific web server only.

Comment: @not2savvy: This is about authentication against a web service which means the context is TLS and not S/MIME. I've made this more clear now that this is about client certificates in TLS only.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Okay, just wanted to avoid misunderstandings here.